# Why Server CPU is exhausted?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Hi guys in my organization they have this react + Nextjs app. they were shipping sourcemaps while running it on Kubernetes (yeah I know this is not right). The developers were pushing the sourcemaps to the sentry server and somehow have forgotten to remove it from the actual container. So I tweaked their build process and removed the sourcemap from the container after the upload process. But a strange thing happened and please dont bash me if its way too obvious, the CPU started getting a lot of hits and was getting exhausted very frequently.

For comparison before and after number are as follows.

barely touching 18% now (>25%) CPU

Disk read used to be (<284 kbps) now its (>300 kbps)

Concurrent conn used to be (< 1.5k) now its (>2.5k).

What i suspect is that while the sourcemaps used to be there it would wait for it to complete the requests and send them sequentially or something like that because I compared the network waterfall and I could see that earlier the requests went sequentially for most of the requests but after sourcemap removal they were more towards parallel. is it some kind of pre caching mechanism which when not finding the sourcemaps starts requesting other resources?

The red one is **before** the sourcemap is removed and the pink one is **after** the sourcemap is removed.

[image: After sourcemap removed]

[image: Before sourcemap removed]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolved**:

The issue was the next-pwa package. not exactly an issue its the behavior. The next-pwa creates a sw.js service worker which maintains a key-value pair of the static resources. its main job is to cache the first requests of these files/resources and then to serve it from the cache itself. if its not found then it reaches to the server. in our case as we had deleted the sourcemaps, but the sw.js still was pointing that it will keep track of these resources hence the requests were increasing with every user or page refresh.

Solution is to install the new version of next-pwa and add a new config called buildExcludes and filter .js.map files while it build its key-value pairs.

Had to understand how the caching works.

Japanese resource but you can understand by translating it.
https://zenn.dev/jj/articles/next-pwa-with-sourcemap